# JDK 1.7 breaks backward compatibility? (generics)

Tags: java, generics, java-7, java-6

I've found similar topics, but overly complicated and not quite the same. So the thing is. Here's the(minimal) code which is fine on 1.6, but doesn't compile with 1.7 javac.

```
public class Test {
    private static class A<T>{};
    private static class B{};
    private static class C{};

    B doSomething(A<B> arg){
        return new B();
    }

    C doSomething(A<C> arg){
        return new C();
    }
}
```

On 1.7 the error is this:

```
java: name clash: doSomething(Test.A<Test.C>) and doSomething(Test.A<Test.B>) have the same erasure
```

I understand the type erasure and why it's a wrong code. I just don't understand why we can have this code in our project compiling and running in 1.6, when 1.7 have problems with it. What is wrong? Is it a bug in 1.6 compiler that it allows us to do so? Is it possible to make it work in 1.7 other than rewriting?

- JDK1.6 javac version: 1.6.0_43
- JDK1.7 javac version: 1.7.0_25

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're quite right, under JLS3 this code should never have compiled and this was a bug in 1.6.

For the release of 1.7 much of the underlying type system was updated and this bug was fixed, the result is better type handling at the cost of some backward compatibility issues.

As for getting it to work in 1.7, I believe re-factoring is your only option.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I still don't like that they broke backwards compatibility.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj: Fixing a bug is not breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: @newacct: I think it is, because a lot of code may depend on it. Do you know a developer who read the whole JLS?

Comment: The point is, @NeplatnyUdaj, if your code depends on a bug then your code needs changing.

Comment: Seems like this could easily become a semantics argument, and I'm curious if there is any official Sun/Oracle comment on it. Regardless of your definition of backwards compatibility, there is code that compiled for an entire major version of the compiler (I presume), and now no longer does. That seems at least worthy of an explanation/debate from the compiler authors.

Answer (score 6):

It is one of the bugs in javac that have been fixed in Java 7 - you can find more information in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities). I'm afraid your only option is to rewrite that code if you want to switch to Java 7.

> **Area**: Tools
>   **Synopsis**: A Class Cannot Define Two Methods with the Same Erased Signature but Two Different Return Types
>   **Description**: A class cannot define two methods with the same erased signature, regardless of whether the return types are the same or not. This follows from the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 8.4.8.3. The JDK 6 compiler allows methods with the same erased signature but different return types; this behavior is incorrect and has been fixed in JDK 7.
>   **Example**:
>
> ```
> class A {
>     int m(List<String> ls) { return 0; }
>    long m(List<Integer> ls) { return 1; }
> }
> ```
>
> This code compiles under JDK 5.0 and JDK 6, and is rejected under JDK 7.

Comment: What exactly was the behavior of `A` under `Java 5` and `Java 6`? Did it actually pick the proper one, or did it just pick the first (or last) one? What about if you try to call it with, say, `List<Double>`?