# Is Changing Java Compiler Level 1.6 to 1.7 Requires All Classes to Deploy?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, java-6, javacompiler

I have java web project in **eclipse Luna**. The compiler level is "**1.6**".

I need some 1.7 functionality so I change the level to "**1.7**" and the java code in the project. There's no compile error.

Now, I'm going to deploy my code. **My question is;**

> Is it safe to deploy only changed class to production? Or do I have
>   to deploy all classes?

**PS:** production server JRE level is 1.7 already.

Regards.

Comment: This link should help you, and based on that, I think it is best to redeploy everything. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613562/jdk-1-7-breaks-backward-compatibility-generics.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally only changed class is enough if there is no dependency on changed class from any other class. If there is any dependency deploy all classes